# How to code "OR" in a Visual Studio project file Exec batch script code

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, batch-processing

I am working with a Visual Studio project file, and I need to modify an Exec command in the AfterBuild block so that two files are excluded from a "move" command.  Specifically, I am trying to modify this:

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(_MyOutputDir)" Command="for /r %%i in (*) do if not &quot;%%~nxi&quot;==&quot;Sync Utility.exe.manifest&quot; move &quot;%%i&quot; &quot;%%i.deploy&quot;" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
```

To do something like this:

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(_MyOutputDir)" Command="for /r %%i in (*) do if not &quot;%%~nxi&quot;==&quot;Sync Utility.exe.manifest&quot; OR &quot;%%~nxi&quot;==&quot;Sync Utility.application&quot; move &quot;%%i&quot; &quot;%%i.deploy&quot;" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
```

I'm getting an error on the "OR" part. I have tried replacing it with "or if not" and "and not" as well with no luck (grasping at straws here). I am told by a coworker this is some kind of batch file scripting, but I am completely unfamiliar with this so any links to outside sources which could help me understand this better would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `OR` with `if not`.  This will create a nested `if`, logically equivalent to 
"and not".